# Resize window to fit content after WM_PAINT

Tags: c++, c, winapi

is there a way to resize after all WM_PAINT calls are done? so that i can automatically resize my window to fit whatever i have painted, since initially my window size is defined at a certain size, there may be leftover spaces that are not painted, how can i remove these leftover spaces?
As you can see from the screenshot below the white spaces are the leftover spaces.
[image]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include "loadFromTextFile.h"

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";
const int recLength = 3;
const int wndHeight = 700;
const int wndWidth = 700;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC            hdc;
HBRUSH blackBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
HBRUSH whiteBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
HBRUSH redBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
HPEN myPen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));

//load from text
string FILE_PATH = ("10x10.txt");
loadFromTextFile loaded = loadFromTextFile(FILE_PATH);
int mazeWidth = loaded.getColumns() * recLength;
int mazeHeight = loaded.getRows() * recLength;
void paintMaze(HWND hwnd, vector<vector<string> > grid){
    hdc = ::BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    SelectObject(hdc, myPen);

    for (int r = 0; r < loaded.getRows(); r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < loaded.getColumns(); c++){

            RECT rect;
            rect.left = c*recLength;//x upper left
            rect.top = r*recLength;//y upper left
            rect.right = (c + 1)*recLength;//x lower right corner
            rect.bottom = (r + 1)*recLength;//y lower right corner

            if (grid[r][c] == "1"){//1 path

                FillRect(hdc, &rect, blackBrush);
            }
            else if (grid[r][c] == "0"){//wall

                FillRect(hdc, &rect, whiteBrush);
            }
            if (r == 50 && c == 50){
                FillRect(hdc, &rect, redBrush);
            }
        }
    }
    DeleteObject(blackBrush);
    DeleteObject(whiteBrush);
    DeleteObject(redBrush);
    DeleteObject(myPen);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_FILE_EXIT:
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
        case ID_ABOUT:
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, mazeWidth, mazeHeight, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:

        {
            paintMaze(hwnd, loaded.getNodeGrid());
        }

        break;


    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        " Maze",
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,//prevent resize
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, wndWidth, wndHeight,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: "*... resize my window to fit whatever i have painted,*" As you painted the content you should know its extents. Just use the latter to resize the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paint in an offscreen buffer.

This allows you to resize the window.

Paint the window by copying the buffer.

Comment: hello, is there any code samples and what technique is it called? i am totally new to win32 gui

Comment: some people call it double buffering. i guess you can find samples easily enough. if not, CreateBitmap, CreateDC and so forth.

Comment: This requires you to be able to create upper bounds on width and height. If you can do that then perhaps it's easy to calculate them size exactly. At which point off screen is not needed.

Comment: where do i resize the window after drawing onto the buffer?